# groupby with transform minmax

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, data-preprocessing

for every city , I want to create a new column which is  minmax scalar of another columns (age).
I tried this an get **Input contains infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').**

```
cols=['age']


def f(x):
    scaler1=preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    x[['age_minmax']] = scaler1.fit_transform(x[cols])
    return x


df = df.groupby(['city']).apply(f)
```

Comment: What are the return values of `np.any(np.isnan(df['age']))` and `np.all(np.isfinite(df['age']))`?

Comment: np.any(np.isnan(df['age']))  = True      np.all(np.isfinite(df['age']))=False

Comment: So it seems that there is at least one NaN in your column which you'll need to handle somehow (drop, fill, etc.) before MinMaxScaler will work.

Comment: I replace all  na to 0 and it still has the same error

Comment: I believe `MinMaxScaler` can handle the nan by itself and the problem is more with inf. what gives `np.all(np.isfinite(df['age'].fillna(0)))`?

Comment: you right .           df['age'].replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)      and it worked.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

```
df['age'].replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Or

```
df['age'] = df['age'].replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
```